# How to automate this popup in chrome using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

In Firefox this popup([screenshot of the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK6Vb.png)) is coming as a window kind of thing and also I am able to save the option as default. But in chrome it is coming as alert kind of popup. How to click the button in this popup using selenium?

Comment: try looking [here](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html)

Comment: you can try this in python

obj = driver.switch_to.alert
obj.accept

Answer (score 1):

Python alert handling

```
#Switch the control to the Alert window
obj = driver.switch_to.alert
#Retrieve the message on the Alert window
msg=obj.text
print ("Alert shows following message: "+ msg )
#use the accept() method to accept the alert if want to dismiss
obj.accept()
```

or if you want to dismiss it

```
obj.dismiss()
```